# Socket communication between Java and C# application

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I have 02 applications, one is written in java and the another one is written in C#. I need to exchange data (Strings) between them thus I use a socket connection.

Currently the C# application acts as server and java application acts as client. The C# application will continuously listen on port "7777" and the Java application will make a socket to "localhost:7777" as start up and use that socket to send data to C# server. I don't close the connection between them since I need to exchange data frequently.

Everything is great until my C# server application sometimes needs to send some Strings to the Java client application. I think about using another port to make my java application becomes a server and the C# application will also become a client. Yet I don't feel that it is a good solution.

P/S: Yes, socket is Bi-direction, in my current application I can send string data from my C# application back to Java application, but only when the Java application first sent a string to the C# application and now it is waiting for the respond data from the C# application.

Thus I want to ask if there is another better solution ? Is it possible if we only use 1 port in total ? Thank you very much.

Comment: as soon as a connection is establised, the servicing socket and the active connect socket on each end are equal and bidirectional. Which means client and server is not really relevant anymore. It is not clear why you would need another socket just for sending strings. Or why you want to reverse the server becoming client and vice versa.

Comment: I was thinking of mentioning this in comments to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253294/socket-communicating-between-java-and-c-sharp-applications). Sockets go both ways. You don't need two of them.

Comment: sorry guys, I made a mistake, what i meant is sometimes, the C# server application needs to send some data to the Java client application, but this is not possible since my Java application can't listening to that port anymore since it is already occupied by the C# application.

Comment: sockets are bidirectional so now I know for sure you don't need an extra socket and because your comment comes after already mentioning this fact  shows you probably don't understand what we mean. The sockets can be used for both receiving and sending using the same socket.

Comment: You need to get your concepts clear here, because it sounds like you're a bit confused. Think about a web request. The browser connects to the server and sends a request to the server. The server replies. All on the same ***single*** socket connection. No new socket is opened up. No new port is required. Once connected, the client can send data to the server and the server can send data back to the client. Sockets allow both reading from and writing *to the same socket instance*. Once the socket is connected, both the client and the server can both read and write.

Comment: Ah I think I got confusion about the coding concept. Since in my java application, if I continue waiting for the message from socket, that will block the whole execution. But I can put this while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){...} to a new thread and it would solve the problem, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Your socket works both ways (bi-directional), so you won't need to create another. You can just get the output stream and input stream of the socket, on both sides of the connection, and use those for sending/receiving.

To send a string, the easiest way would probably be to use a DataOutputStream as you can write UTF-8 strings with a simple function.

Java side:

```
String blah = "hey";
DataOutputStream dataOs = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOs.writeUTF(blah);
```

The C# side is slightly trickier as you need to account for the fact that the first two bytes sent from the java function writeUTF() will actually be the length (in bytes) of the string that follows. You can grab those 2 bytes first and then throw them into an int, shifting the bits as you go along. Then you can use that int as the size of the buffer when you request the string from the socket. Should look something like this.

C# side:

```
int length = 0;
byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[2];
socket.Receive(sizeBuffer);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeBuffer.Length; i += 1)
{
    length = length << 8;
    length += sizeBuffer[i];
}

byte[] stringBuffer = new byte[length];
socket.Receive(stringBuffer);

string myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringBuffer, 0, stringBuffer.Length);
```

Comment: Hi, in my current situation, I can handle this since my C# application is a server and my java application is a client, what i need is sending data from my c# application back to the java application.

Comment: Once the connection establishes, the notion of client and server is pretty much gone. You then just have two endpoints that each can send/receive.  If you want to send data to the Java app from the C# app, just grab the output stream on your C# socket and use that. Then grab the input stream on the Java side and read from there.